# Enabling SSL on an AWS EC2 instance

Tags: apache, ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

On an EC2 instance that services multiple domains via Virtual Hosts, I have set up a Load Balancer that forwards HTTPS traffic from port :443 to :8443 for one of the domains, in part following this example: http://elwoodicious.com/2009/12/23/using-elb-to-serve-multiple-domains-over-ssl-on-ec2-for-giggles/

My working httpd.conf Virtual Hosts look like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.om
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias *.domain.com
    ErrorLog logs/domain.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/domain.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>

# more VirtualHosts on *:80 here
```

Now, as soon as I add a new virtual host for the same domain.com, like so,

```
<VirtualHost _default_:8443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.om
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias *.domain.com
    SSLEngine On
    RequestHeader set X_FORWARDED_PROTO 'https'
    ErrorLog logs/domain.com-https-error_log
    CustomLog logs/domain.com-https-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

...Apache fails to restart. There are no error notices - it just says `[FAILED]`.

The only clue I have: even when I remove all *:80 Virtual Hosts and only leave a single one for port *:8443, Apache fails... even when setting `NameVirtualHost *:8443`.

Could this mean it's an EC2 directive of some sort that only allows Virtual Hosts on port 80?

Thanks for any help!

---------------- Edit: add error log

`var/log/httpd/error_log` contains this:

```
[Tue Jun 09 16:52:37 2015] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Jun 09 16:52:37 2015] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Tue Jun 09 16:53:13 2015] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Tue Jun 09 16:53:47 2015] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Tue Jun 09 16:53:47 2015] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Jun 09 16:53:47 2015] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Jun 09 16:53:47 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.29 mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/1.0.1k-fips configured -- resuming normal operations
```

`var/log/httpd/ssl_error_log` contains this:

```
[Tue Jun 09 16:53:47 2015] [warn] RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Tue Jun 09 16:53:47 2015] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `ip-xx-xx-xx-xx' does NOT match server name!?
```

And finally, `var/log/httpd/domain.com-https-error_log` looks like this:

```
[Tue Jun 09 16:53:13 2015] [error] Server should be SSL-aware but has no certificate configured [Hint: SSLCertificateFile] (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1026)
```

On line 1026 of httpd.conf is `<VirtualHost _default_:8043>`. I've uploaded the self-signed OpenSSL certificate I created on my local computer using the `aws cli`, and I attached it to the Load Balancer for HTTPS traffic.

The CNAME record for the domain points to the ELB DNS Name as well. Not sure what I missed.

Comment: it says [FAILED] on the commandline, but there should be info in the error log.

Comment: @tedder42 thanks for the hint. I updated the question to add the logs. It looks like a problem with the self-signed certificate I created with OpenSSL on my local computer... Could that be the cause for Apache failing to start? It's "only" a [warn] so I didn't consider it for this issue, but was planning to look into it later.

Comment: @tedder42 I updated the question again with a log I neglected to check before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great. The error messages helped. You're missing two lines:

```
SSLCertificateFile /directory/to/file.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /directory/to//file.key
```

[Here's a howto on configuring SSL on Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html).

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know where AWS stores those files - I uploaded them using the AWS CLI ( http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/upload-server-certificate.html ). I'm not sure if it will work like this because the certs are attached to the Load Balancer, just like this particular EC2 instance. I don't think the cert files are even stored on the same box as the instance.

Comment: if you are trying to have the ELB do your SSL termination (not just SSL passthrough), only the ELB needs the certs and your host will think it is sending plain http. In other words, configure your listeners for 80->80 without SSL and 443->80 with SSL.

Comment: "Passthrough" gave me the hint I needed... I had to upload the certs to the instance instead of attaching them to the ELBs; then I was able to reference them per your answer. Thank you!